# UrlFetchApp Post Variables Not being sent/received by php server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api, urlfetch, google-apps-script-editor, google-apps-script-api

```
 var headers =  {
            "Accept": "application/json", 
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        };

 var data =  {
            action: "test123"
        }; 

      var options = { "method":"POST",
            "headers" : headers,
            "followRedirects": false, 
            "validateHttpsCertificates": false, 
            "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "payload": JSON.stringify(data)
           };

var requestURL = "http://requesturl.com/controller.php";

var response =   UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestURL, options);

      Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

on the php server in controller.php

```
<?php

echo ($_POST['action']);

?>
```

I get nothing for the echo but I do get a 200 response code, any help would be much appreciated!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

What result do you get trying the code:

```
var data =  {
        'action': 'test123'
    }; 

  var options = { "method":"POST",
        "headers" : headers,
        "followRedirects": false, 
        "validateHttpsCertificates": false, 
        "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload": data
       };
```

Comment: action post var does not populate, its empty, do you think it might have to do the way the apache server is configured on godaddy? what do you get?

Comment: also I think you forgot JSON.stringify function for data?

Comment: @papelerto configuration might not be the problem.

Comment: what do you think could be the issue? i follow the examples perfectly on the adwords scripts examples, do you think my server reads and responds to http headers differently somehow?

Comment: literally its what i posted above it does not even work for the minimum case which i posted, can you receive post params? does the code work for you?